# What is "finishing Torah" and how it stems from Solomon's prophecy?

Tags: torah-study, siyum

One of the sources for celebrating finishing a Talmud tractate is in [Kohelet Raba 1, 1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kohelet_Rabbah.1.1.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) (or almost same in Shir Hashirim Rabah):

> ...,אָמַר רַבִּי יִצְחָק: חֲלוֹם עוֹמֵד עַל כַּנּוֹ
>   ,"מִיָּד "וַיָּבוֹא יְרוּשָׁלָיִם ... וַיַּעַשׂ מִשְׁתֶּה לְכָל עֲבָדָיו
>   .אָמַר רַבִּי יִצְחָק מִכָּאן **שֶׁעוֹשִׂין סְעוּדָה לְגָמְרָהּ שֶׁל תּוֹרָה**
>
> Says R' Yitzchak: The dream [**of Solomon's prophecy**] was immediately fulfilled... Immediately "he went to Jerusalem, ... and he made a feast for all of his servants." Says R' Yitzchak, from here we learn that one makes a feast on completing the Torah.

I understand that King Solomon was happy for the generous gift from Hashem and fulfillment of the prophecy, and made a great Thanksgiving feast.

What is "finishing Torah" in this statement and how does the celebration stem from Solomon's feast?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88631/15579

Comment: Why'd you remove that paragraph? That was the most interesting part