# How reliable is the Nikkud in our books?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, vowels-nekudot

As we all know, in Hebrew, the Nikkud can change a lot. When studying for [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104897/what-is-finishing-torah-and-how-it-stems-from-solomons-prophecy), I notice slight deviations between different books and I'd like to know how reliable the Nikkud in our books is?

In other words, are the differences between different spellings attributed to their publishers or they are original?

For example, compare [Kohelet Rabba 1,1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kohelet_Rabbah.1.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (same in print):

> אָמַר רַבִּי יִצְחָק מִכָּאן שֶׁעוֹשִׂין סְעוּדָה
>   לְגָמְרָהּ שֶׁל תּוֹרָה. (Komotz under ג)

and the resulting Halachah (Yo"D תרס"ט) in Mishnah Berurah (different editions):

> ועושין בו סעודת משתה לִגְמָרָהּ של תורה (Shbo in ג)

Can it be traditional for some type of books, but not others? For example, we all know that Tanach is vowelled traditionally, but what about the Midrashim?, and I guess, Rambam or Shu"A or M"B surely weren't.

Comment: The last example looks very strange - 2 shevas next two each. Is the first a chirik?

Comment: Surely sometimes works originally included Nikkud and sometimes it was added by a later editor. What else do you seek?

Comment: @JoelK Right you are!

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe you know for sure that Nikkud in Halachic books cannot be trusted, unlike Midrashim, or maybe none except Tanach.

Comment: @AlBerko I have a Chumash with many mistakes in nikud and even spelling. It all depends on the publisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from Tanakh, the nikkud of midrashic/halakhic books are generally reconstructed by later scholars and there could be either variant readings or actual grammatical errors.  (There are even different variants of the SAME text, but that's a different subject.)  The masorah of the Tanakh - including the nikkud - was codified with minor variants more than 1,000 years ago, so it's generally pretty reliable; but there were variant readings even back then which are well documented.  On a related note, I've seen quite a few grammar errors in siddurim, especially from smaller publishers.